# Autohotkey RegexMatch помогите достать число из строки

Tags: autohotkey

Нужно из этой строки достать первое число 64

"likeStatus\":\"INDIFFERENT\",\"likeCount\":64,\"likeCountText\":{\"simpleText\":\"64\"},\"likeCountWithLikeText\":{\"simpleText\":\"65\"},\"dislikeCount\":4

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/pBzGxk/1

Comment: @splash58 И как это сделать в Autohotkey ? По такому примеру мне выдает ошибку